# ReactiveCocoa convert single signal into values

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I've been using ReactiveCocoa for a while, but I've always been doing this:

```
// Assume match.status is an enum
[RACAble(self.match.status) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber * matchStatusNum) {
    // sets self.background.color and self.label.visible
    [wself renderMatchStatus:matchStatusNum.intValue];
}];
```

But it seems like it would be better to bind directly to the stuff I care about. more like this:

```
RACSignal * matchStatus = RACAble(self.match.status);

RAC(self.background, color) = [matchStatus ???]; // expects a UIColor
RAC(self.label, visible) = [matchStatus ???]; // expects a BOOL
```

How do I convert a signal into different stuff? All the examples use `combineLatest:` and `reduce` but I only have one signal, and reduce and map throw errors.

How would you organize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `map:`

```
RAC(self.label.visible) = [matchStatus map:^(NSNumber*status) {
    return @(status.intValue == MatchStatusStarted);
}];
```